# Sorting a php multidimensional array by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array stored as $data
I have another var called $col that indicates the key to search by e.g. 0, 1, 2 etc.
I have a var called $dir that indicates the direction: asc or desc

I'd like to sort the array $data based on the $col and $dir  variables and save the result to the same variable name $data for use later in my script.

i've tried usort, asort etc without luck as I think this may need to be a loop?

```
    [237] => Array
        (
            [0] => 509
            [1] => 2019-09-13
            [2] => test <==== order by this key
            [3] => QUOTED 
            [4] => Overdue
            [10] => 11
        )

    [238] => Array
        (
            [0] => 510
            [1] => 2019-10-20
            [2] => Road      <==== order by this key 
            [3] => QUOTED
            [4] => Overdue:
            [10] => 11
        )
```

e.g. in the above example $col=2 and $dir=asc which means I need to order all array results in ascending order by key "2".  So the main array order would be 238, 237.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`uasort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), `u` for user-defined sort and `a` to retain key values. I've assumed you're using PHP7 and thus have access to the [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) (`<=>`):

```
$col = 2;
$dir = "asc";
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($col, $dir) {
    return ($dir == "asc") ? $a[$col] <=> $b[$col] : $b[$col] <=> $a[$col];
});
print_r($array);
```

Output:

Array

```
(
    [238] => Array
        (
            [0] => 510
            [1] => 2019-10-20
            [2] => Road
            [3] => QUOTED
            [4] => Overdue:
            [10] => 11
        )
    [237] => Array
        (
            [0] => 509
            [1] => 2019-09-13
            [2] => test
            [3] => QUOTED
            [4] => Overdue
            [10] => 11
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nUvLS)

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you!   uasort rather than usort made quite the difference. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_multisort` with `array_column`

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 2), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

DEMO :- https://3v4l.org/D6Y58